# How to calculate the total value of two object arrays with the same key but different fields and combine them into one using aggregation in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, group

I have data returned as an array like this:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("65aa4921c767f95a70b8867f"),
    "creator" : "Henry",
    "date" : "2023-12-22",
    "channels" : [
        {
            "key" : "HTV",
            "value" : 1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("65aa4921c767f95a70b8867f"),
    "creator" : "Max",
    "date" : "2023-12-23",
    "channels" : [
        {
            "key" : "VTC",
            "value" : 1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("65aa4921c767f95a70b88689"),
    "creator" : "John",
    "date" : "2023-12-23",
    "channels" : [
        {
            "key" : "VTC",
            "value" : 2
        },
        {
            "key" : "HTV",
            "value" : 1
        }
    ]
}]
```

I want to group by date and elements in the "channels" array with the same key will merge into one
(Total value of channels with the same key and sum of all values of channels)

I used aggregate to group "date":

```
model.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            date: '$date'
          },
          Total: { $sum: { $sum: '$channels.value' } }
        }
      }
    ])
```

But don't know what to do next (merge duplicate keys into one, and calculate the sum of the value)

My expected results:

```
[{
    "date": "2023-12-22",
    "channels" : [
        {
            "key" : "HTV",
            "value" : 1
        }
    ],
    "Total" : 1
},
{
    "date": "2023-12-23",
    "channels" : [
        {
            "key" : "VTC",
            "value" : 3   // 1 + 2
        },
        {
            "key" : "HTV",
            "value" : 1
        }
    ],
    "Total" : 4
}]
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Very grateful for the responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is:

1. `$unwind` to separate the channels into documents
2. `$group` by both `date` and `key` to sum the value
3. `$group` by `date` only
4. Format the response

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$channels"},
  {$group: {
      _id: {date: "$date", key: "$channels.key"},
      value: {$sum: "$channels.value"}}
  },
  {$group: {
      _id: "$_id.date",
      channels: {$push: {key: "$_id.key", value: "$value"}},
      Total: {$sum: "$value"}
  }},
  {$set: {date: "$_id", _id: "$$REMOVE"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jfb049nGauQ)

Answer (score 0):

May be you shuould try to unwind the array field and perform the sum operation. Unwinding will create multiple documents with same _id fields depending on the number of array elements you have. Then may be you can perform the operation by grouping based on _id and caculate total value for particular keys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will like something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $group: {
  _id: "$date",
  channels: {
    $push: "$channels"
  }
}
},
{
 "$addFields": {
  "channels": {
    "$reduce": {
      "input": "$channels",
      "initialValue": [],
      "in": {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$$value",
          "$$this"
        ]
      }
    }
   }
  }
 },
 {
  $addFields: {
  channels: {
    $map: {
      input: {
        $setUnion: "$channels.key"
      },
      as: "a",
      in: {
        key: "$$a",
        value: {
          $reduce: {
            "input": {
              $filter: {
                input: "$channels",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$a",
                    "$$this.key"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "initialValue": 0,
            "in": {
              $sum: [
                "$$value",
                "$$this.value"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  total: {
    $sum: "$channels.value"
  }
  }
 }
])
```

**Explanation:**

1. **$group** by date and push in channels array all channel arrays.
2. **$addFields/$reduce** to flatten the arrays of channels array via $reduce to be easier in the next stage.
3. **$addFields/$map/$reduce/$filter** to replace the channels array with new one having sum of values per key ( get unique values via setUnion) to map over unique keys and sum values per key. Also add the total key summing all values per channel array.

The solution maybe best for documents with huge channel arrays since you avoid $unwind operation here.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jrMggPVlJwf)

Comment: Very appreciated for your response